# Is there any reason not to bring about eternal darkness?

Tags: okami

I am a god and I can control the sun and the moon. During the day everything is nice and pretty, but during the night I can find buried treasure thanks to the shining rays of light showing me their location. Because of this I tend to keep the land in perpetual night, except when it needs to be daytime for a quest.

Am I missing anything by doing this? Is there anything that is only available during the day, like the light shafts are only visible at night? Animals, people, enemies, collectibles - everything seems to be available at night as well.

Answer (score 3):

Birds are not available for feeding at night. If you want to achieve having fed all types of animals, you'll need daytime for that.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Disagree: The question asserts that animals are available at night - birds aren't. The achievement 'All Creatures Great and Small' requires feeding each of the bird types as well as the mammal types.

Comment: So, in the future, please provide detailed answers.  In general, one sentence answers are not acceptable here.

Answer (score 1):

I have finished the PS2 version of the game twice.
The only difference I remember is that at night there are more demons.
There were puzzle-like situations that required day or night specifically but they are mostly obvious.
Though I remember searching on google for something and the solution turned out to be making it night.

Comment: Can you provide any more information about that last point? Though if anything, it's more support for my 12-step _1000 Years of Darkness_ programme.

Comment: I don't remember it clearly to be honest. The last time I played the game was about 3 years ago.
But if I remember correctly in those puzzle like situations you had to draw a crescent even if it was night, or draw a sun even if it was day. Not too sure though.